# When trying to call method inside onClick method of a button, it is throwing an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I just started learning Next.js and wanted to try something straightforward. I wanted to display a button on my page that when clicked would show "clicked" in the console.

this is the code that I added to page.js in the default template that is generated when you run npx create-next-app.

```
export default function Home() {
    const handleClick() => {
        console.log('clicked');
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={handleClick} >Click me</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

It's throwing error when I tried to run this

the fixes I have tried till now....

```
return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => handleClick} >Click me</button>
        </div>
)
```

this was throwing an error

> ```
> error Error: Event handlers cannot be passed to Client Component props.
>   <button onClick={function} children=...>
>                   ^^^^^^^^^^
> If you need interactivity, consider converting part of 
> this to a Client Component.
>    at stringify (<anonymous>)
> digest: "1701345382"
> null
> ```

I also tried

```
return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={(handleClick} >Click me</button>
            </div>
    )
```

It was also throwing the same error

Comment: `onClick={handleClick}` is what you're after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next js renders the page on Server side by default. But event happens in browser. So at top of that nextjs file, mention 'use client' it converts the component into client side.

---

```
'use client'

import { useState } from 'react'

export default function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Click me</button>
    </div>)}
```

---

Refer Next js docs: https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#the-use-client-directive

Comment: Thanks a Lot Vyan Lynx . I just didn't realise it is so.

Answer (score 2):

The `onClick` property expects a function, so...

```js
onClick={() => handleClick()}
```

This way you are passing an anonymous function with no parameters that calls `handleClick` with no parameters.

You could also do:

```js
onClick={(event) => handleClick(event)}
```

This way, you are passing the event property to the `handleClick` function.

Or

```js
onClick={handleClick}
```

This way, you are passing every parameter to the `handleClick` function.
It is the same as writing

```js
onClick={(event, ...params) => handleClick(event, ...params)}
```

Finally, when you write

```js
onClick={handleClick()}
```

`handleClick()` is not a function, it is what is returned from `handleClick` function.

Answer (score 0):

What I have learned while doing some React is that: (correct me if I am wrong)

I we are using arrow function to pass the onclick handler then you will have to call the `handleClick`  function.

Try changing it to:

`<button onClick={() => handleClick()}> Click me </button>`

(we need `()` after function here)

This syntax is mostly used if we would want some parameters to be passed in `handleClick` function.

Otherwise, we can also do it like this:

`<button onClick={handleClick}> Click me </button>`

(we don't need `()` after function here)

If we would have done:
`<button onClick={handleClick()}> Click me </button>`

Then the `handleClick` function would have been ran without our clicking the button as soon as this line of code is executed while everything is rendering on the page.

As it happened with you!
Hope it helps :D

Comment: Please check the question now Brother... I have already tried what you suggested. But it is throwing errors.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried converting that component to a client component, with adding `'use client';` at the top of the file? [Because all components in Next by default are server components](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials), therefore for client side interactivity you need to use 'use client'.

Comment: Please read existing answers before posting your own. This answer does not provide any new information beyond [existing answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76490427/215552).

Comment: Posted the answer at roughly the same time :) Tried to provide good source so it took a while to answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this

```
     const handleClick=()=>{
           console.log("clicked")
       }
```

Comment: this still throws the same error ... I suppose u asked me to define the function this way.

Comment: Adding an explanation of how to use provided code and perhaps more importantly, why/how it works, often leads to better answers.